# Write an ng-pattern Allow Special Text and Number

Tags: angularjs

I have form . I want to Allow input Special text and Number Only.
Example : Allow Number and Special text "N/A" or maybe "NA".

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="UpdateKPI.KPIInPeriodInMonth" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" required>
```

Please help me :

Comment: There are enough examples on net.. Google it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can do it with custom directive :-
  <input type="text" ng-model="number" required="required" numbers-only="numbers-only" />

Js:
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('numbersOnly', function(){
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
           // this next if is necessary for when using ng-required on your input. 
           // In such cases, when a letter is typed first, this parser will be called
           // again, and the 2nd time, the value will be undefined
           if (inputValue == undefined) return '' 
           var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9+.]/g, ''); 
           if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
              modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
              modelCtrl.$render();
           }         

           return transformedInput;         
       });
     }
   };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.number = ''
}
```